# trouble setting up firebase auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up firebase auth for a portfolio-building project.  I am using react as a front end, and in the firebase documentation it says to post web credentials at the bottom of the body tag.  I am using react, so I am not using a body tag, and it is not clear to me where to post this.  I am also getting an error

```
Line 71, parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}";
  69 |       
  70 |       var firebaseConfig = {
> 71 |         apiKey: "_apikey_",
     |               ^
  72 |         authDomain: "_domain_.firebaseapp.com",
  73 |         databaseURL: "https://_domain_.firebaseio.com",
  74 |         projectId: "_projectid_",
```

.  Can someone please take a look at this and help get me started with firebase auth?  Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Topbar from './components/Topbar'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

var firebase = require('firebase');
var firebaseui = require('firebaseui');

function Home() {
 return (
    <div>
      <Topbar />
      <div  className = "MakeACheap">
        <p>Make a Cheep</p>

      </div>
      <div className = "InputBox">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div className = "Chirpfeed">
      <p>Chirp Feed</p>
      </div>



    </div>
  );
}

function Register() {
 return (
    <div>
      <Topbar />


    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Router>
    <div>
        <Switch>

          <Route path="/register">
          <Register />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>

        </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>



    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>

      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "_apikey_",
        authDomain: "_project_.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://_project_.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "_projectid_",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "1043088880002",
        appId: "_Appid_",
        measurementId: "G-YXC3FVYE48"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>
</div>
  );


}

export default App;
//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to use analytics you can paste the code inside script tag in index.html file in your public folder.

else if you want to integrate more things from firebase, I would instead suggest you create another file for firebase initialization eg. firebase.js

```
npm install firebase
```

import firebase to the file

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

put the config in this file only

```
       var firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "_apikey_",
                authDomain: "_project_.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://_project_.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "_projectid_",
                storageBucket: "",
                messagingSenderId: "1043088880002",
                appId: "_Appid_",
                measurementId: "G-YXC3FVYE48"
    }

      var fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fireApp;
```

now import this file in you app.js and run functions, like

```
import fireApp from './yourdirectoryPath';

     var analytics = fireApp.analytics();
        analytics.logEvent();
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks Udit!  I believe another useful resource would be the tutorials at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY3hwwB-Uq4.  Firebase gets update frequently so I was having a hard time finding a relevant tutorial, but this looks to be it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Matt123 No problem :)